# almacenar informacion en un ciclo foreach

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un ciclo foreach para recorrer todos los estados y necesito que en la variable se me almacenen todos los estados pero solo me esta almacenando el ultimo estado, como puedo hacer para que no sustituya el valor por cada iteración? aca el codigo del controlador

```
 foreach ($estados as $estado) {
        $datos['codigo_estado'] = $estado['codigo_estado'];
        $porEstados =  $this->modelo_base_m->cuentaPorEstados($datos);
    }
```

y aca el codigo del modelo

```
   public function cuentaPorEstados($datos){
  extract($datos);
  $cadena = "(fecha_registro >= '$fecha_inicio' AND fecha_registro <= '$fecha_fin') AND (edad >=0 AND edad <=120)";
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('dean_eapg.v_evaluaciones');
  $this->db->where($cadena);
  $this->db->where('codigo_estado',$codigo_estado);

  $rs = $this->db->get();
  $resultado = $rs->result_array();
  return $resultado;
}
```

El siguiente código fue respusta de Rodrigo logra el cometido de la pregunta pero se repite por cada campo el código es el siguiente:

```
<?php
$request = [1,"darinel cigarroa","24","2021-12-16 00:00:00","2021-12-16 00:00:00"];
$consulta = "";
$colums = ["id","nombre","edad","created_at","updated_at"];

foreach ($colums as $campo)
    {
        foreach($request as $rows){
           $consulta .= $campo . '=' . $rows . ", ";
        }
    }
# El ultimo elemento temrinara en ", "
# Lo eliminaremos usando preg_replace
$consulta = preg_replace("/\s*\,\s*$/", "", $consulta);

print($consulta);
```

El resultado de esto es:

```
id=1, id=darinel cigarroa, id=24, id=2021-12-16 00:00:00, id=2021-12-16 00:00:00, nombre=1, nombre=darinel cigarroa, nombre=24, nombre=2021-12-16 00:00:00, nombre=2021-12-16 00:00:00, edad=1, edad=darinel cigarroa, edad=24, edad=2021-12-16 00:00:00, edad=2021-12-16 00:00:00, created_at=1, created_at=darinel cigarroa, created_at=24, created_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00, created_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00, updated_at=1, updated_at=darinel cigarroa, updated_at=24, updated_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00, updated_at=2021-12-16 00:00:00
```

Por lo que noto es que se repite cada campo con todos los valores vere la forma de resolver y comparto en cuanto pueda lograrlo.

Comment: Intenta sacar la instancia del modelo después del **foreach** para que se ejecute una sola vez y declarar el array _$datos_ antes del mismo **foreach**

Answer (score 4):

Te almacena el último estado por que cada que ingresas al ciclo se está reemplazando el valor antes guardado por el nuevo valor, si quieres almacenar todos los estados deberías usar un array:

```
foreach ($estados as $estado) {
    $datos['codigo_estado'] = $estado['codigo_estado'];
    $porEstados[] = $this->modelo_base_m->cuentaPorEstados($datos);
}
```

Comment: nota informativa: `porEstados[] = $this->modelo_base_m->cuentaPorEstados($datos)` sería lo mismo que `array_push()`... igual que hace `$datos['codigo_estado'] = $estado['codigo_estado']` y no se necesitaría de iniciar la variable `$porEstados = array();`

Comment: @aldanux oh pensé que la mejor forma de hacerlo era con array_push() debido a que es la función que implementa php para eso

Comment: [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php) tienes más información... _Si se utiliza array_push() para añadir un solo elemento al array, es mejor utilizar $array[] = ya que de esta forma no existe la sobrecarga de llamar a una función._ Saludos

Comment: @aldanux Muchas gracias por la aclaración, he editado la respuesta, saludos!